# BAD HEADER: nonencoded 8-bit character issue

Tags: php, email, csv

I'm using PHP `mail()` to send e-mails with attached CSV file. My problem is that the server is putting some of these (most of them actually) mails in quarantine due to. According to the log the reason is:

```
mail.info:Sep  9 21:34:08 mailout4 amavis[18812]: (18812-05-2) Passed BAD-HEADER-2 {RelayedOpenRelay,Quarantined}, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] <xyz@ws15.surf-town.net> -> <xyz@xyz.com>, mail_id: skJU2BMP1ssu, Hits: 1.117, size: 5145, queued_as: BB1DE33018, 2571 ms

BAD-HEADER-2 refers to: CC_BADH.',2',   "id=%n - BAD HEADER: nonencoded 8-bit  character",
```

So I'm thinking that this occurs due to some special chars in the CSV file data?

The code sending the mail looks like this (there are more code, but this shows you the mail header, etc).

```
//create attachment from array of data $csvdata
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string($csvData,$filename))); 

// Make the body of the message
$body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "$body\r\n"
    . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "$attachment\r\n"
    . "--$multipartSep--";

 $subject .= ' (' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ')';

 $headers = array(
   "From: $from",
   "Reply-To: $from",
   "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
 );   

 $recievers = explode(','.$to);
 foreach ($recievers as $reciever) {
   mail($reciever, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers)); 
 }
```

Has any of you encountered this problem?

Any ideas on a fix that doesn't require changing the server setup?

Comment: Just use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Your life will be easier ;)

Comment: could you post the headers as well? (don't forget to obfuscate the sender mail address ;))

Comment: @giorgio: this is the header $headers = array(
    "From: $from",
    "Reply-To: $from",
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
  );

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear (enough): could you post the parsed headers? As there seems to be a character in there that shouldn't belong there (might be a non-printable character of some sort)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The cause is international characters in the headers. You should check the contents of the mail headers. If you have access to the amavis mail server that rejects the message, you can fix it changing the amavis configuration:

`$allowed_header_tests{'8bit'} = 0;`

Hope this helps.